# Apt-get Cant find package: libav-tools_2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb

Tags: apt, package-management, opencv

I have been spending hours trying to install OpenCV3 for Ubuntu.

One of the dependencies is:

`sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev`

However, when I run that, I get:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavutil-dev_2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libswresample-dev_2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavcodec-dev_2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavformat-dev_2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libswscale-dev_2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
```

Going to the address `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg`, it seems like they only host `libavutil-dev_2.8.15`.

I found a place that still hosts the older version [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libavutil-dev/7:2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)

Can I install for there? What do I do now?

(also, I tried to run `sudo apt-get update` with no effect)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just download this package and install it: `wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/364831898/libavutil-dev_2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i libavutil-dev_2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb`

Comment: thanks so much, this was exactly what i was looking for :-)